# How to render an animation made with a python Script

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have a simpĺe python script that triggers an animation base on the location of a cube.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.objects['Text']

def recalculate_text(scene):
    x = scene.objects['Cube'].location[0]
    obj.data.body = '{0:.1f}'.format(x)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```

Using a text Object it shows the location of the cube in the Viewport.

The problem is that because my python skills are very basic, i can't Render the animation; once i hit "Render animation" ( Itried: EEVEE and CYCLES: Image sequence and video) it only shows the first frame of the text object.
[Here is the Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DqQ3N5KX/)

Comment: The "Duplocate" solution did not work

Comment: Why not? "*Doesn't work for me*" doesn't really tell us what you've tried and where it failed, nor can we suggest other alternatives.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried to change the things that answered the question (the Duplicate), like frame_change_post and add scene,depsgraph, print(depsgraph), obj = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph). But that did not work. As i mentioned in my question, my Python knowledge is very basic, and this could look easy for some one that knows Python, but for me it is not and that's why i asked for some help

Comment: The code in the dupe is actually working pretty well, you just have to call `evaluated_get(depsgraph)` on the cube itself -> Demo: https://pasteall.org/iA93, output as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwNhz.png

Comment: @brockmann not sure why is not working, i also copy and pase the code directly to a blend file and nothing happens, not even in the viewport now. I'm also testing Blender 2.81, 2.83 (from blender website, linux versions) and 2.90.1 (linux snap)

Comment: I can confirm that is working only on my 2.80 Blender (linux), not sure why

Comment: No issues on windows/blender 2.90.1, blend: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DRQePDdQ -> Open up the file, run the script and move the cursor in the timeline.

Comment: Still nothing? Any news or further issues?

Comment: No, just 2.80, i ended up using that Blender version to make the project, thanks for everything

Comment: Just can tell that the blend file I posted is working across all versions on all systems for me. If you do not willing to provide any further information, I can't do much for you...